# Can I use Jest with Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I was developing Angular4 project and was looking for Unit test frameworks. Angular has Jasmine and Karma as default frameworks. But I came accross Jest developed by facebook.In their documentation, they have repeatedly used react keyword. But can I use 'Jest' for angular4 unit testing? Any downfall if I use jest with angular4? Or any suggestions for other Unit test frameworks?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use jest with Angular4.

You can refer [Testing Angular 4 with Jest](https://www.xfive.co/blog/testing-angular-faster-jest/) to get started.

Comment: Oh Thanks Gokul.

Comment: But have you faced any problems while using jest with angular?